# LSTM custom Loss function caued error. ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, loss-function

I tried to implement LSTM with custom function by

```
tf.random.set_seed(7)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(18,1 ), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(LSTM(100))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='tanh'))

def LossQuat(y_true, y_pred):
        a, b = y_true.get_shape()
        error = []
        for i in range(a):
            w0,x0,y0,z0 = y_true[i,:]
            w1,x1,y1,z1 = y_pred[i,:]/tf.norm(y_pred[i,:], ord='euclidean', axis=None, keepdims=None, name=None)
            w = w0 * w1 - x0 * x1 - y0 * y1 - z0 * z1
            error.append(tf.square(2*tf.math.acos(w)))
        err = tf.reduce_sum(error)
        return tf.reduce_mean(err) 

model.compile(loss=LossQuat, optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5),run_eagerly=True)

model.summary()
```

But I get this error

```
Epoch 1/150

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-17-8e2657a2f86a> in <module>()
----> 1 history=model.fit(X,Y, verbose=1,epochs=150, batch_size=32)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    690       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    691         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 692           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    693         else:
    694           raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-16-820055073eb4>", line 15, in LossQuat  *
        w1,x1,y1,z1 = y_pred[i,:]/tf.norm(y_pred, ord='euclidean', axis=None, keepdims=None, name=None)

    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

When I use this custom loss function to train FFN, the model will train without any error.
I understand that this error is related to LSTM layer but I don't now how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use tf.unstack to unpack the values, like:`w1,x1,y1,z1 = tf.unstack(y_pred[i,:]/tf.norm(y_pred[i,:], ord='euclidean', axis=None, keepdims=None, name=None), axis=1)`